# pick random shapes from array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, underscore.js

I want to pick two or three shapes from array but I can't. I tried this code:

```
var range = _.sample(shapes, 2);
```

this code run but is not random.

```
var range = shapes.length-2 * Math.random();
```

Comment: undersjorejs _.sample(arr, n) returns random sample. How do you know it's not random?

Comment: I have a feeling this question should have been tagged with underscore...

Comment: @Sonia let us know if any of the answers solved the problem. If not, please provide more details. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will get 1 random element from the array

```
var shape = shapes[Math.floor(Math.random() * shapes.length)];
```

You could turn this into a function that makes it a little easier to work with

```
function sample(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}
```

Now it's easier to get multiple random shapes

```
var shape1 = sample(shapes);
var shape2 = sample(shapes);
```

However, it's possible that in the above example `shape1` and `shape2` could be the same result. Think of rolling a die: It's possible that both outcomes could be a `4`.

Perhaps this is not what we want. Perhaps what we want is more like a numbers lottery where the numbers 1-50 exist in a bucket, and once a number is removed from the bucket, it's not possible for it to be picked again.

To do that, we'd have to adjust the function a little bit

```
function sample(arr, count) {
  // default sample size of 1
  if (!count) count = 1;

  // create a copy of the original array
  var copy = arr.slice(0);

  // init samples with empty array
  var samples = [];

  // use a loop to sample n-items
  for (var i=0; i<count; i++) {
    // get the index of a random item
    var idx  = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);

    // remove it from the copy of our array,
    // and add it to the samples result
    samples = samples.concat(copy.splice(idx, 1));
  }

  // return the samples
  return samples;
}
```

Now you can see it will never show a duplicate

```
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
sample(letters, 3); // ["e", "c", "b"]
sample(letters, 3); // ["e", "a", "d"]
sample(letters, 3); // ["c", "a", "b"]
```

---

We could make a useful adjustment to this code though. Consider the following:

To take a random sampling of 2 playing cards from a deck, we could do this in two ways

1. pick 2 cards from 2 random positions of sorted/unsorted deck
2. shuffle the deck and take 2 cards of the top

So far the `sample` function we wrote uses a method more like **#1**. But, if we write it using a method like **#2**, we could get an array shuffling function for free! Cool!

Let's see how that would look

```
function random(x) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * x);
}

function shuffle(arr) {
  var copy = arr.slice(0);
  return arr.reduce(function(shuffled, elem) {
    var idx = random(copy.length);
    return shuffled.concat(copy.splice(idx, 1));
  }, []);
}

function sample(arr, n) {
  return shuffle(arr).slice(0, n || 1);
}
```

Now, we've met the original goal and received bonus reusable functions `random` and `shuffle` as a side-effect of writing `sample` as a higher order procedure **^.^**

Answer (score 1):

**Update** Question seem to be related to underscore.js and not arrays in general, so here is a small update -

You seem to be using the [_.sample()](http://underscorejs.org/#sample) call correctly, but you need to use the result as an array as well when you specify sample values > 1:

```
var shapes = ['circle','star','square','hexagon','triangle','polygon'];
var range = _.sample(shapes, 2);  // => ["square", "triangle"]; (example result)
```

There is therefor no need to use `Math.random()` to select any items as the items now are randomly picked anyways. Just iterate over the array to use the actual value from each index.

**Example**

```
... other code ...

for(var i = 0, shape; shape = range[i]; i++) {  // will loop through the range array

    switch(shape) {                             // current item
        case "square":                          // (not 0 etc. as in the original code)
            ... code for square here...
            break;

        case "triangle":
            ... code for triangle here...
            break;

        ... etc. ...
    }
}
```

[Old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29810557/1)